# Mac backup through VLAN

Tags: mac, time-machine, backup, vpn

I have 5 users with Mac laptops who want an automatic backup to be performed whenever they get to one of the three sites of their business (3 VLAN's connected via VPN). The Mac users connect to the network via Wi-Fi (same Wi-Fi network, same SSID on the three sites). The network is PC only, and the Mac laptops do not need the services of this network (they only need Wi-Fi to be able to go on the internet).

What would be the best solution for a Time Machine backup to start as soon as they connect to the Wi-Fi at any of the 3 sites? A server? A NAS? The Macs must stay independent, and not mix with the rest of the network.

If it's a server, should it simply be configured with an IP address in the range the VPN server serves the portables themselves?

Does anyone has dealt with this kind of situation?

Miguel

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Have you tried creating a AFP share on the network? The Macs could then be given a profile which gives them the necessary login information for the wireless network and account name and password for the AFP share. You could also have it automatically add the Time Machine setting so that it backs up to the AFP share point. But to know more, what have you tried thus far?

Comment: I did not try anything yet. The existing network is PC only and they want to keep it like that, separated from the 5 MacBooks. The only thing "allowed" is the Wi-Fi connection for internet use, hence the need for a new machine (server or NAS) that would be backing up the Macs. However, they want to be able to do so whenever they get to one of the 3 business sites.